# How to change or add class of jquery mobile loader widget?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Based on the documentation here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/loader/#option-classes

There is a way to change or add `ui-loader`(default class of loader widget).

However I have tried it, but somehow it doesn't change anything. Here is my demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/yusrilmaulidanraji/u1q4xjnt/4/

Is there anything that I miss?

Comment: I don't believe that this class can be changed, as the internal logic of jQuery Mobile relies on that class being fixed. You can add other classes to the spinner as needed, though. For what reason do you need to do this?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan As you could see in my demo, I tried to increase basically the width of my loader's ui by customizing `.ui-loading .ui-loader` in my css. However it affects also the default loader. Thus, I assumed I can try to specify the class of my custom loader then.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest targeting the specific loader you want by placing a class on a parent element and hooking the CSS to that, eg. `.parent-element .ui-loading .ui-loader { width: ... }`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I dont think I can do that. Because `ui-loader` is right under `body` element, which will still affect the default loader then if I try `body .ui-loading .ui-loader { width: ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, I have tried all the examples from its documentation, but the classes option still won't do anything. Therefore, I end up by changing it programmatically from js. Here is my demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yusrilmaulidanraji/u1q4xjnt/6/

Html:

```
<button id="hideLoading"></button>
```

Css:

```
.abv-loading-text{
  width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}


.ui-loader-custom {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Js:

```
var loadingUI =
    "<label class='abv-loading-text'>Wait on this screen until the process is complete.</label>" +
    "<span class='ui-icon-loading'></span>" +
    "<h1></h1>";
$.mobile.loading("show", {
  html: loadingUI,
  textVisible: true
});
$(".ui-loader").addClass('ui-loader-custom');



$("#hideLoading").on("click", function () {
    $(".ui-loader").removeClass('ui-loader-custom');
    $.mobile.loading("hide");
});
```